# Who is the 'topper' in all the four subjects?

Tags: logic

Answer the questions on the basis of the information given below. Five students A, B, C, D and E studied in the same class. They had $4$ subjects viz. English, Physics, Chemistry and Maths. In each subject they were ranked according to the marks obtained in that particular subject. The student with higher marks was given higher rank. Maximum marks that can be obtained in all subjects are same and no two students got the same marks in any subject. **Top three students in each subject were considered as 'toppers'.**

**Additional Information given**:

$1$. Every student except C got the same rank in two subjects.

$2$. No student got the same rank in any other subject as he got in Physics.

$3$. A stood just behind B and just ahead of E in Physics.

$4$. In Maths, D finished just ahead of C, who had as many persons ahead of him as behind in Chemistry.

$5$. Neither B nor E got third rank in any subject.

$6$. E got the same rank in English as D got in Chemistry.

$7$. Only D got same ranks in English and Maths.

$8$. The student who got second rank in Chemistry, got higher rank than D in Maths.

$9$. The student who got first rank in Maths was not the topper in English.

$10.$ Only one student was topper in all four subjects.

$11$. No student got last rank in more than $1$ subject.

$12.$ A got first rank in English and D got fifth rank in Chemistry.

**Who is the 'topper' in all the four subjects?**

**Attempt:** I could deduce that the ranks of $A:~1$ in English,$3$ in physics.

Rank of $B: 2$ in physics

Rank of $C: 3$  in Chemistry

Rank of $D: 5$  in Chemistry

Rank of $E :5$ in English, $4$ in Physics

With such huge information, I find it a bit perplexing how to process everything. Anyone knows how to move ahead? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo. I meant $B$ has rank $2$ in physics. edited it

Answer (score 2):

From clue 2, D cannot get 5 in Physics so must get 1.
C gets 5 in Physics
The all topper must be A because B did not get any thirds and cannot have two firsts and two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

1. $D$ is rank 3 in English: you know it's $(A, ?, ?, ?, E)$ but you know from clue [5] rank 3 cannot be $B$, and you know from clue [1] it cannot be $C$ since $C$ is rank 3 in chemistry.
2. Maths is $(?, ?, D, C, ?)$: by clue [7], $D$ has the same rank in English as in maths, which is 3, and is just ahead of $C$ by clue [4].
3. $B$ is rank 4 in English, $C$ is rank 2: this is by clue [7]. You know $D$ is the only student with the same English and maths ranks, so if $C$ is rank 4 in maths then they can't be rank 4 in English, and therefore must be rank 2. This completes English as $(A, C, D, B, E)$.

At this point you can conclude $A$ is the topper in all subjects; all other students have at least one rank 4 or below. If you want to continue:

4. The order in maths is $(E, A, D, C, B)$: by clue [9], you know the first rank in maths must be either $B$ or $E$; it cannot be a topper in English, which are $A, C, D$. But $A$ is the topper in all subjects, so $A$ must be rank 2. This tells you $E$ is rank 1, since $E$ cannot be rank 5, which contradicts clue [11]. Thus the order in maths is $(E, A, D, C, B)$.
5. $C$ is rank 5 in Physics: by clue [11], the only student of $B, C, D, E$ without a last rank is $C$.
6. $E$ is rank 4 in Physics: by clue [2], you know $E$ can't be rank 1, since they are rank 1 in maths already. By clue [5], it can't be rank 3 either, so it must be rank 2 or 4. But if it were rank 2, then this contradicts clue [3], since $A$ is ahead of $E$, so $A$ must be rank 1, but $A$ is also behind $B$, which is impossible.
7. The order in physics is $(D, B, A, E, C)$: by clue [3].
8. $E$ got rank 1 in chemistry: this follows by clue [1]. You know $A$ is in the top 3 since $A$ is a topper, and $C$ we know is rank 3 in chemistry by clue[4]. If $B$ was in the top 3 then $B$ must be rank 1, since rank 2 must be someone who got higher than $D$ in maths, i.e. either $A$ or $E$. But $B$ can't be rank 1, since this contradicts [1], so it must be $E$ in the top 3. By clue [1] again you know $E$ must be rank 1.
9. The order in chemistry is $(E, A, C, B, D)$: since $A$ is a topper so $A$ must be rank 2, which leaves $B$ as rank 4.

Answer (score 1):

When you use(3) , we know a sequence BAE should be seen in physics therefore one of B,A,E must be 3rd.As B and E cannot be 3rd this B is second in physics , A is 3rd and E is 4th.

We know A is first in english and D is 5th in chemistry.Hence E is 5th in english by (6). No body secures last rank in more than 2 subjects hence D is not fifth in physics but physics is left with 2 slots only hence D is first in physics and C is 5th in physics .

As C is just behind  of D in maths it cant be 1st in maths . D cannot be first in maths(as he is in physics ) so C cant be second. As C is 3rd in chemistry and 5h in physics so it cant take those positions in maths . C can only take 4th in maths and D is 3rd.

As D have same ranks in english and maths , hence it is 3rd in english.As B is 2nd in physics, meaning cannot be second in english. 1st,3rd and 5th have been taken . Therefore B is 4th and C is 2nd in english.

As E took 5th in english , D took 5th in chemiatry , C took 5th in chemistry , B took 4th in english hence they cant be topper in all subjects. Hence A is topper in all subjects(one student is). A can't take 4th in chemistry and neither can E(4th in physics). C and D are already known 3rd and 5th in chemistry . And hence B is 4th in chemistry.

As E,D,C have already taken 5th position in english, chemistry and maths so cant take 5th in maths . Neither can A because he is the topper. So B is 5th maths.

A cannot be ist in maths (he is in english) so he is 2nd and E is 1st.

E has to have same ranks in 2 subjects hence is 1st in chemistry and 2nd is A in chemistry. I think some information are extra which i did not use to solve the question.I never used (8) and (9) in my solution

---

Final table is

$$
\begin{matrix}
X & English & Chemistry & Physics & Maths \\
1st & A & E & D & E \\
2nd & C & A & B & A \\
3rd & D & C & A & D \\
4th & B & B & E & C \\
5th & E & D & C & B \\
\end{matrix}
$$